# route all l2tp connetion to ssh tunnel Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ssh, l2tp

I have two server, server1 and server2. The OS of both is Ubuntu 22.04. I have setup l2tp server on server one. I can tunnel from server1 to server2 by ssh.
My question is  how can I route all traffics server1 to server 2 by tunnel.
The sshuttle solution did not work for me in server1.
In other way that i can explain:
I would like to connect on my local PC via l2tp connection to server1 and when I have type "my ip" in google search, it has been shown server 2 IP.

The l2tp connection is important for me. I know the ssh tunnel method between my PC and server1 and server 2 is possible but I wont.

Comment: The title says Ubuntu but nothing in the question tells me Ubuntu.

Comment: both server has ubuntu 22.04. I have corrected  my question. thanks